# i18n react vite typescript project - Error 404 netlify build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, netlify, i18next

I'm using the i18n js library in my project, this works perfectly fine when running the project on a local server, the problem arises when i try to deploy the project with github and netlify (the project actually successfully deploys). When i then open the site as preview in the netlify dev window the page loads, as well as the background color, but not any dom elements at all).

Error message from the console
GET index-8b67d650.js:3489
https://64d27ba5475b0e06e32c96df--sprightly-shortbread-8aa727.netlify.app/LINK%20TO%20PROD/i18n/en.json 404

The language.json file are saved in the /dist/public/i18n/en.json.

How come the filepaths are wrong when the project is built and not when it is ran with the local server?